# Printing pdf file in cordova

Tags: cordova

In my app mobile cordova, I would like to start printing a pdf file downloaded from a remote url.
I fouded some plugin such [phonegap-print-plugin](https://github.com/mohamed-salah/phonegap-print-plugin) and [cordova-plugin-printer](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer), but they only allow printing of text content or html documents.
There are tools that can satisfy my request?

Comment: I'd suggest opening the pdf in other app (like acrobat) and then print from that app. You can use fileOpener2 plugin to open the pdf with the associated app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the plugin you suggested and save pdf file in a not private directory. Then, through Acrobat Reader or an app designated for my printer, I was able to open the PDF file and print it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a cordova plugin that will print a pdf from a base64 encoded string without having to open it in another app first.

https://github.com/sarahgoldman/cordova-print-pdf-plugin

Comment: Do you have plans to support Windows Mobile?

Comment: Hello sgoldman,
I was checking out your project and I was wondering if you could put up an example of usage with an actual base64 string on the Github guide. It would be really appreciate it. Also, maybe another example using your other plugin to convert to base64 and then print! Thank you for all your work! Nice plugin! Also what do you mean when you say "type: file/data" does that mean it takes an absolute path to a file, and data means base64 string? Anyways, if you could specify on the doc it would be amazing!!

Comment: Some installation instructions would be nice, but thanks for the work Sarah

Answer (score 1):

If you want use cordova-plugin-print-pdf from Ionic 2/3, you need access from Typescript world to Javascript. In new Ionic are many plugins. The clue is, you load from Npm the wrapper file. I don't found no wrapper, here the snippet.

It’s only the print function implemented.

You need add this modul in app.module.ts und in the module, where you plan the use.  In same way you can use from new Ionic all “old” plugins. Possible you need to debug while failures, you can remote-debug from Developer-Console in Chrome.

```js
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var PrintPDF = function () {
  this.METHOD = 'printDocument';
  this.IS_AVAILABLE_METHOD = 'isPrintingAvailable';
  this.DISMISS_METHOD = 'dismissPrintDialog';
  this.CLASS = 'PrintPDF';
};

PrintPDF.prototype.print = function(options) {

  options = options || {};

  var data = options.data; // print data, base64 string (required)

  var type = options.type || 'Data'; // type of document

  var title = options.title || 'Print Document'; // title of document

  var dialogX = options.dialogX || -1; // if a dialog coord is not set, default to -1.
  // the iOS method will fall back to center on the
  var dialogY = options.dialogY || -1; // screen if it gets a dialog coord less than 0.

  // make sure callbacks are functions or reset to null
  var successCallback = (options.success && typeof(options.success) === 'function') ? options.success : this.defaultCallback;

  var errorCallback = (options.error && typeof(options.error) === 'function') ? options.error : this.defaultCallback;

  // make sure data is set
  if (!data) {
    if (errorCallback) {
      errorCallback({
        success: false,
        error: "Parameter 'data' is required."
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  var args = [data];

  if (device.platform === "iOS") {
    args.push(type);
    args.push(dialogX);
    args.push(dialogY);

  } else {
    args.push(type);
    args.push(title);

  }

  // make the call
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, this.CLASS, this.METHOD, args);

};

PrintPDF.prototype.isPrintingAvailable = function (callback) {

  // make sure callbacks are functions or reset to null
  var successCallback = (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') ? callback : this.defaultCallback;

  cordova.exec(successCallback, null, this.CLASS, this.IS_AVAILABLE_METHOD, []);

};

PrintPDF.prototype.dismiss = function () {

  // Dismiss is only an iOS method because the dialog exists in the
  // same context as the cordova activity. In Android, when the
  // print activity starts, the cordova activity is paused.

  if (device.platform === "iOS") {

    cordova.exec(null, null, this.CLASS, this.DISMISS_METHOD, []);

  }

};

PrintPDF.prototype.defaultCallback = null;

// Plug in to Cordova
cordova.addConstructor(function () {
  if (!window.Cordova) {
    window.Cordova = cordova;
  };

  if (!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
  window.plugins.PrintPDF = new PrintPDF();
});
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var PrintPDF = function () {
  this.METHOD = 'printDocument';
  this.IS_AVAILABLE_METHOD = 'isPrintingAvailable';
  this.DISMISS_METHOD = 'dismissPrintDialog';
  this.CLASS = 'PrintPDF';
};

PrintPDF.prototype.print = function(options) {

  options = options || {};

  var data = options.data; // print data, base64 string (required)

  var type = options.type || 'Data'; // type of document

  var title = options.title || 'Print Document'; // title of document

  var dialogX = options.dialogX || -1; // if a dialog coord is not set, default to -1.
  // the iOS method will fall back to center on the
  var dialogY = options.dialogY || -1; // screen if it gets a dialog coord less than 0.

  // make sure callbacks are functions or reset to null
  var successCallback = (options.success && typeof(options.success) === 'function') ? options.success : this.defaultCallback;

  var errorCallback = (options.error && typeof(options.error) === 'function') ? options.error : this.defaultCallback;

  // make sure data is set
  if (!data) {
    if (errorCallback) {
      errorCallback({
        success: false,
        error: "Parameter 'data' is required."
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  var args = [data];

  if (device.platform === "iOS") {
    args.push(type);
    args.push(dialogX);
    args.push(dialogY);

  } else {
    args.push(type);
    args.push(title);

  }

  // make the call
  cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, this.CLASS, this.METHOD, args);

};

PrintPDF.prototype.isPrintingAvailable = function (callback) {

  // make sure callbacks are functions or reset to null
  var successCallback = (callback && typeof(callback) === 'function') ? callback : this.defaultCallback;

  cordova.exec(successCallback, null, this.CLASS, this.IS_AVAILABLE_METHOD, []);

};

PrintPDF.prototype.dismiss = function () {

  // Dismiss is only an iOS method because the dialog exists in the
  // same context as the cordova activity. In Android, when the
  // print activity starts, the cordova activity is paused.

  if (device.platform === "iOS") {

    cordova.exec(null, null, this.CLASS, this.DISMISS_METHOD, []);

  }

};

PrintPDF.prototype.defaultCallback = null;

// Plug in to Cordova
cordova.addConstructor(function () {
  if (!window.Cordova) {
    window.Cordova = cordova;
  };

  if (!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
  window.plugins.PrintPDF = new PrintPDF();
});
```

When you debug the Javascript on your Android with Remote-Debug here are usefull breakpoints in cordova.js:

**function build(module)**
 To check the modules -all modules, not just plugins- check which are loaded.
If a module does not exist, there is no error message, but the previously empty object remains. Return module.exports includes the methods of the plugin

**onScriptLoadingComplete(moduleList, finishPluginLoading)**
In the "modullist" include all plugins. These will assigned to the "symbollist". The "symbollist" consists of type (Clobber, Merge, Default, Run), PluginName and Clobber. Clobber is the "pluginRef" to which the functions are addressed, usually window, cordova or navigator

**exports.injectScript**
The URL of the code of the modules is passed. the  tag with this URL is added to the HTML element "document.head".

CodeExample:https://github.com/alpinea310/ch.schb.rav.mobil